# Auto increment features downwards - top of map to bottom map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-sort

is there a method/tool that can auto increment based on spatial location.

I have tried a auto increment by "sort" based on (polygon centroids) X,Y coordinates but this doesn't really work that well if the polygons are irregular in location.

What I want is an unique ID for each property starting from 1 (top of map) to n (bottom of map) but going from left to right and not jumping around.

For example (see below) - I want "14" to be "13", "18" to be "14", "20" to be "15" and so on going down the map.

[image]

Comment: Draw the line and run near tool on it with location. Compute distance from line start to points(nearx, neary).. Sort by using Results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logically asign values to polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271591/logically-asign-values-to-polygons)

Answer (score 1):

The [Sort](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm) tool has a spatial_sort_method that can do this:

> Specifies how features are spatially sorted. The sort method is only
>   enabled when the Shape field is selected as one of the sort fields.
>
> ...
>
> UL — Sorting starts at upper-left corner.

However, it needs an Advanced level license:

> Sorting by the Shape field or by multiple fields is only available
>   with an Desktop Advanced license.

The same can be accomplished using a Basic level license but that needs ArcPy code to be written.